# remove product from category using rest-api

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to remove a lot of product from a category in my store

i tried to use update product and editing the category properties in the product, this one

PUT /wp-json/wc/v3/products/

this is the script i used

```
for ($i=0; $i < 22; $i++) {
  $products = $woocommerce->get('products?category='.$categoryToRemove.'&per_page=50&page=1');

  $update_data = array();

  foreach ($products as $key1 => $product) {
    if(count($product->categories)>1){
      foreach ($product->categories as $key2 => $category) {
          if($category->id == $categoryToRemove){
          unset($product->categories[$key2]);
        }
      }
    }
    $woocommerce->put('products/'.$product->id, ['categories' => $product->categories]);
  }

}
```

the product property doesn't changed when i checked it and the product still show inside the cateogories in the store and when i'm call all products via api by filtering the category.

Comment: You need to clear the transients... `WooCommerce > Status > Tools : WooCommerce transients`

Comment: Ok, it seems i miss typed the question a bit, correcting and adding more detail, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

There are a few way's you could go about this.

Let's start with what you've been doing already trying to Update the Products.

My Advice is updating individual products, Either one at a time or Batches

You can find the Official doc on this here [Link](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#batch-update-products)

So we'll want to update `"status": "publish",` To something like `"status" : "draft"`

We do this with `[PUT] /wp-json/wc/v3/products/<id>`
E.G

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/batch \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{ "update": [
    {
      "id": 799,
      "default_attributes": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "status": "draft",
          "name": "Color",
          "option": "Green"
        },
        {
          "id": 0,
          "status": "draft",
          "name": "Size",
          "option": "M"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Now We can also approach this by "Deleting" a product either permanently or moving it to the Trash

We do this one of 2 ways

This will move the product to trash

````
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret```

This will Permanently delete the Product
````

```
curl -X DELETE https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/794?force=true \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret
```

So in your case, You're using "Put" to try and Remove a product, So your telling the API Hey Update this product and giving it nothing to update so It just Refreshes the Product.
Now you mention you remove the Product on Click So I can see you retrieve the Individual Products ID, So if we want to Delete it simply

```
$woocommerce->DELETE('products/'.$product->id,'?force=false');
```

Comment: Hi, what i meant to do is not delete the product from the store, but to remove the product from a certain category.

Comment: So you want to remove a Product from Category A to then add to Category B later type of thing?

Comment: Ah I see what the  ['categories' => $product->categories]) is for, Well if you have the update function sorted, If you cant manage to update anything, Trying making ```$woocommerce->put('products/'.$product->id, ['categories' => $product->categories]);``` to ```$woocommerce->PUT('products/'.$product->id, ['categories' => $product->categories]);``` Capital PUT

Comment: Using all capital PUT still doesn't work, i'll see if there is problem with the unset method i used